# Data race in boost threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool

I'm trying to create a methode with threadpool, but when i'm starting use this function the result is incorrect. I think that was data race error, because each thread try to write into freq_dictionary at the same time, but i don't know how make it right(

```
void InvertedIndex::UpdateDocumentBase(std::vector<std::string> input_docs) {
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < input_docs.size(); ++i) {
        boost::asio::post(pool, boost::bind<void>([&,i] {
            std::stringstream ss(input_docs[i]);
            std::string word;
            while (ss >> word) {
                std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), tolower);
                if (freq_dictionary.find(word) == freq_dictionary.end()) {                            
                    std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Entry>> pair;
                    pair.first = word;
                    Entry curEntry{static_cast<size_t>(i), 1};
                    std::vector<Entry> entryVec;
                    entryVec.push_back(curEntry);
                    pair.second = entryVec;
                    freq_dictionary.insert(pair);
                } else {
                    bool added = false;
                    for (auto &entry: freq_dictionary[word]) {
                        if (entry.doc_id == static_cast<size_t>(i)) {
                            entry.count++;
                            added = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!added) {
                        Entry newEntry{static_cast<size_t>(i), 1};
                        freq_dictionary[word].push_back(newEntry);
                    }
                }

            }
        }));
    }
    pool.join();
}
```

Moreower I recive this "expression:crtisvalidheappointer block" in bad cases, or simply wrong answer.
If I use simply 1 thread the result will be correct, but I want to improve the threadpooling.

Comment: Unrelated: You shouldn't take the address of `tolower` (see _Designated addressable functions_) and you should cast the `char` to `unsigned char` before calling `tolower`. Also, don't transform each individual word. Do it once for the whole string:  `std::transform(input_docs[i].begin(), input_docs[i].end(), input_docs[i].begin(), [](char ch) { return std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); });`

Comment: _"each thread try to write into freq_dictionary at the same time, but i don't know how make it right"_ - You need synchronization, like a `std::mutex` that you lock when you need to access to `freq_dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

Due to the locking required parallelization will not be particularly fast(er). In fact it could well be slower, depending on the nature of your data.

If it is very rare for new words to be added, even within a document, you might be happy with locking and making the counter atomic. At least also move the input document to the posted task. I renamed `freq_dictionary` to `histo` here:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4002beba50a8a5e5)**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

struct InvertedIndex {
    void UpdateDocumentBase(std::vector<std::string> input_docs);

    struct Entry {
        size_t             doc_id;
        std::atomic_size_t count;

        Entry(size_t doc_id, size_t count) : doc_id(doc_id), count(count) {}
        Entry(Entry const& rhs) : doc_id(rhs.doc_id), count(rhs.count.load()) {}
    };
    using Entries = std::vector<Entry>;
    std::map<std::string, Entries> histo;
    std::mutex _mx;
};

void InvertedIndex::UpdateDocumentBase(std::vector<std::string> input_docs) {
    constexpr int            N = 4;
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(N);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < input_docs.size(); ++i) {
        post(pool, [doc = std::move(input_docs[i]), this, i] {
            std::stringstream ss(std::move(doc));
            for (std::string word; ss >> word;) {
                boost::algorithm::to_lower(word);

                if (auto hit = histo.find(word); hit != histo.end()) {
                    Entries& ee = hit->second;
                    auto eit = find_if(begin(ee), end(ee), [i](Entry const& e) {
                        return e.doc_id == i;
                    });

                    if (eit != end(ee)) {
                        eit->count++;
                    } else {
                        std::lock_guard lk(_mx);
                        ee.push_back(Entry{i, 1});
                    }
                } else {
                    std::lock_guard lk(_mx);
                    histo.emplace(word, Entries{{i, 1}});
                }
            }
        });
    }
    pool.join();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> input_docs;
    {
        std::vector const fnames(argv + 1, argv + argc);
        size_t            total_size = 0;

        for (std::filesystem::path fname : fnames) {
            std::ifstream ifs(fname);
            input_docs.push_back({std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {}});
            total_size += input_docs.back().size();
        }
        std::cout << "Read " << fnames.size() << " documents ("
                  << (total_size >> 10) << "KiB)\n";
    }

    InvertedIndex ii;
    ii.UpdateDocumentBase(std::move(input_docs));

    struct Occurrence {
        std::string_view w;
        size_t           n;
    };
    std::vector<Occurrence> occ;

    namespace v = std::views;
    for (auto& [w, entries] : ii.histo) {
        auto counts = entries | v::transform(&InvertedIndex::Entry::count);
        auto total  = std::accumulate(begin(counts), end(counts), 0);
        occ.emplace_back(w, total);
    }

    auto nth = occ.begin()+10;
    std::ranges::partial_sort(occ, nth, std::greater<>{}, &Occurrence::n);

    for (auto& [w, n] : occ | v::take(10))
        std::cout << "Occurs " << n << " times: " << std::quoted(w) << "\n";
}
```

Prints (for 55 random Coliru sample programs):

```
Read 55 documents (49KiB)
Occurs 303 times: "{"
Occurs 255 times: "<<"
Occurs 213 times: "}"
Occurs 190 times: "="
Occurs 128 times: "#include"
Occurs 122 times: "int"
Occurs 90 times: "return"
Occurs 84 times: "//"
Occurs 83 times: "};"
Occurs 71 times: "const"

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.052s
```

### Being Smarter

I'd suggest making the loop less granular, and possibly merging the results after completion. OpenMP and even std::execution parallel algorithms make that easier than raw threading.